# Javascript for google map not responding correctly to ajax request in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, google-maps-api-3

In rails I have a bunch of 'notices' in the html, each of which has latitude and longitude attributes for a corresponding marker on a google map. I send an ajax request to the notices controller when the google map boundaries change. It returns all notices with coordinates inside the map boundaries, and also an array containing all the information necessary for the map to place the corresponding markers.

javascript in the view:

```
var initialize, map, mapOptions;
var markers = [];

initialize = function() {
  mapOptions = {
    center: {lat: 51, lng: 0},
    zoom: 9
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', dealWithNewWindow);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', dealWithNewWindow);
  function dealWithNewWindow(event) {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var nelat = bounds.getNorthEast().lat();
    var swlat = bounds.getSouthWest().lat();
    var nelng = bounds.getNorthEast().lng();
    var swlng = bounds.getSouthWest().lng();
    var mapBounds = {NElatitude:nelat, SWlatitude:swlat, NElongitude:nelng, SWlongitude:swlng};
    $.ajax({
      type     : 'POST',
      url      : '/maprequest', 
      dataType : 'script',
      data     :  {  NElatitude:nelat, SWlatitude:swlat, NElongitude:nelng, SWlongitude:swlng }
    });
  };
  dealWithNewWindow(e);
};

makeMarkers = function(markerArray) {
  // alert("Alert 1.");
  for (m = 0; m < markerArray.length; m++) {
    // alert("Alert 2.");
    (function(marka) {
      var goomap = google.maps;
      var marker = new goomap.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new goomap.LatLng(marka.lat, marka.lng),
        infowindow: marka.infowindow,
        id: marka.id
      });
      markers.push(marker);
    }(
      markerArray[m]
    ));
  }
};
```

notices controller show action:

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js do
      @notices = noticefeed
      @markers = []
      @notices.each do |notice|
        marker = Marker.new(notice.latitude, notice.longitude, notice.content, notice.id)
        @markers.push(marker)
      end
      gon.markers = @markers
    end
  end
end

private
  def noticefeed
    nelat = params[:NElatitude]
    swlat = params[:SWlatitude]
    nelng = params[:NElongitude]
    swlng = params[:SWlongitude]
    Notice.where("      latitude  < ?
                    AND latitude  > ?
                    AND longitude < ?
                    AND longitude > ?  ", nelat, swlat, nelng, swlng )
  end
```

show.js.erb:

```
$("#notice_list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @notices) %>")
makeMarkers(gon.markers);
```

The browser console shows that the ajax is sent correctly and that the server responds without a problem. The line `$("#notice_list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @notices) %>")` is providing the correct html. The problem is that the markers on the map are not created or updated. (I'm using gon to communicate between rails and jquery). When I uncomment `alert("Alert 1.");` the alert appears, meaning it is successfully calling the makeMarkers method, but `alert("Alert 2.");` never appears when it is the only one uncommented. Therefore makeMarkers is being called, but it never makes it into the `for (m = 0; m < markerArray.length; m++)` loop. Therefore it mustn't be happy with being passed `gon.markers`. 
Why are the map markers not being updated?

EDIT:

In show.js.erb, when I replace `makeMarkers(gon.markers);` with `makeMarkers([1,2,3])` it successfully enters the for loop ("Alert 2" appears). There must be something wrong with gon.markers. gon.markers is an array that was created in the notices controller inside ruby, do I have to somehow turn it into a javascript array? I thought gon did this for you?
I've checked using debugger that gon.markers and @markers are arrays or markers, and they are:

gon.markers:

```
[#<Mymodule::Marker:0x0000010ded1c38 @lat=51.9714995840941, @lng=-1.60000814589637, @infowindow="This is great!!", @id=904>]
```

So when this object is handed to makeMarkers, something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your makeMarkers() js function doesn't associate the array of markers to your map canvas.

(My code for this is structured differently with the google maps api implemented in JavaScript, with nothing google map related in the controller.)

After you do your full marker array push, as you do, you must then associate your marker array with the map.

```
// Sets the map on all markers in the array.
function setAllMap(map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < your_marker_array.length; i++) {
    your_marker_array[i].setMap(map);
  }
}
```

To show the markers:

```
    // Shows any markers currently in the array.
    function showMarkers() {
      setAllMap(map);
    }
```

And for the sake of completeness, to clear the markers:

```
// Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
function clearMarkers() {
  setAllMap(null);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't explain why makeMarkers is successfully called but doesn't enter the `for (m = 0; m < markerArray.length; m++)` loop?

Comment: Yep. There's a good chance there's more than thing going on here I'm not familiar with gon. I used js and the google maps API 3 straight up. Maybe someone else who is familiar with the gon component can help more. Thanks for letting me know your thoughts.

Comment: I've added this as a comment rather than an answer because it is a solution to the problem but not an explanation of why gon.markers is not accepted by makeMarkers. 
Avoiding gon altogether and using the following code in show.js.erb does the trick:
`makeMarkers(<%=raw @markers.to_json %>);`